# How to load css and js by specific controller on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline, production-environment

How to load css and js by specific controller on rails for both local development and production (Using Heroku)

This will load all the stylesheets and javascipt:

> admin controller :

- admin.css
- admin.js
- user.css
- user.js

> user controller :

- admin.css
- admin.js
- user.css
- user.js

But i want it to load from specific controller

Ex:

> admin controller :

- admin.css
- admin.js

> user controller :

- user.css
- user.js

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Usually it is preferred to load less files (even if they are bigger), because they will be cached afterwards anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different layouts for different views and use specific files for it.

```
admin folder->
 file1.css
 file.2.css
 application.css => there your files
user folder->
  the same as admin
```

than create two files inside `layout folder` `admin.slim` and `user.slim`

and in `application_controller.rb` set layout for your needs
[layout docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout)

```
layout :set_layout


  private

  def set_layout
    case controller
    when 'user'
      "user_layout"
    when "admin"
      "admin_layout"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```